# android permission for internet connectivity for higher API level

Tags: android

I am connecting my app to my server

Below is my manifestation file for accessing internet

```
 <uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="10"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

It is working in API level 10

But when it comes to API level 19 for kit kat version it is unable to access internet it throws exception.

Should I need to add any other permission

This is the code i used to connect to my server

```
public class Discussion_server extends AsyncTask<String,Void,JSONObject> {


static String jsonstring="";
private Handler handler = new Handler();
private ProgressDialog dialog;
private Activity activity;

public Discussion_server(Activity activity)
{
    Log.d("progressing","progressing");
    this.activity = activity;
    this.dialog = new ProgressDialog(activity);
   // onPreExecute();
    dialog.setMessage("Contacting Remote Site");
    dialog.show();
  handler.postDelayed(new Runnable()
  {

    @Override
    public void run() {

        onExecute();    

    }

  },3000);


}


protected void onExecute(){ 


   dialog.dismiss();

}



@Override
protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     try{

    Log.d("boooooo","beeeee");
   // Toast.makeText(this,comment,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    String link="http://www.diveintojava.com/Discussion/mobile_discussion.php";

    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpGet request = new HttpGet();
    request.setURI(new URI(link));
    HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);

    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader
    (new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();


    String line=null;
   jsonstring="";
    while((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
    {
        Log.d("na","na");

        jsonstring+=(line+ "\n");
       //break;
    }
    //onPostExecute();
    return new JSONObject(jsonstring);
 }catch(Exception e){
     Log.d("veaadsldsld","sdlkfsdlfsldklfsd");
    Log.d("exc",e.getMessage());
    //Toast.makeText(activity,"Connection timed out!!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
     return null;
 }



}



}
```

Here is what my logcat shows

```
07-10 02:23:39.827: E/AndroidRuntime(838): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-10 02:23:39.827: E/AndroidRuntime(838): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.diveintojava1/com.example.diveintojava1.Discussion}: java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message
07-10 02:23:39.827: E/AndroidRuntime(838):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180) 
07-10 02:23:39.827: E/AndroidRuntime(838):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
07-10 02:23:39.827: E/AndroidRuntime(838):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
07-10 02:23:39.827: E/AndroidRuntime(838):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
07-10 02:23:39.827: E/AndroidRuntime(838):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-10 02:23:39.827: E/AndroidRuntime(838):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-10 02:23:39.827: E/AndroidRuntime(838):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
07-10 02:23:39.827: E/AndroidRuntime(838):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-10 02:23:39.827: E/AndroidRuntime(838):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-10 02:23:39.827: E/AndroidRuntime(838):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
07-10 02:23:39.827: E/AndroidRuntime(838):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
07-10 02:23:39.827: E/AndroidRuntime(838):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-10 02:23:39.827: E/AndroidRuntime(838): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message
07-10 02:23:39.827: E/AndroidRuntime(838):  at android.util.Log.println_native(Native Method)
07-10 02:23:39.827: E/AndroidRuntime(838):  at android.util.Log.d(Log.java:138)
07-10 02:23:39.827: E/AndroidRuntime(838):  at com.example.diveintojava1.Discussion_server.doInBackground(Discussion_server.java:100)
07-10 02:23:39.827: E/AndroidRuntime(838):  at com.example.diveintojava1.Discussion.onCreate(Discussion.java:78)
07-10 02:23:39.827: E/AndroidRuntime(838):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
07-10 02:23:39.827: E/AndroidRuntime(838):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
07-10 02:23:39.827: E/AndroidRuntime(838):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
07-10 02:23:39.827: E/AndroidRuntime(838):  ... 11 more
```

Comment: Post your code which to use to connect to your server and also post the stack trace.

Comment: I think there is no problem in connection to server because its working in android phones using gingerbread.But when it comes to kitkat version its saying permission denial.I read that some permission is to be added .What permission should i add

Comment: `Post your code which to use to connect to your server and also post the stack trace.` AND tell which exception!

Comment: If you are running it on the UI thread then it will run fine on Gingerbread but it will throw an exception in post Honeycomb devices.Are you connecting to your server in an `AsyncTask` or `Thread`?

Comment: I am connecting in Async task only

Comment: Which exception? `Post your code which to use to connect to your server and also post the stack trace.`

Comment: @venugopal You need to post your Logcat for that.

Comment: I edited my code see that

Comment: WHICH EXCEPTION ? Please post the logcat! Or don't you know what it is/how to do that?

Comment: from your logcat I can say that exception has nothing to do with internet permission it is NPE and as per the stack trace it has something to do with`println` method. can you please highlight to which are the lines 100 in `Discussion_server.java` file and line 78 in `Discussion.java` file.

Comment: Looks like you're passing a null text to `Log.d`, possibly the exception doesn't provide a message. Try `Log.d("exc", "exception" , e);`

Answer (score 0):

The used url "http://www.diveintojava.com/Discussion/" gives html output. Before you used "http://www.diveintojava.com/Discussion/mobile_discussion.php" which gives json text. You need json text for the json parser.

Comment: I added the logcat sorry for the delay

Comment: `java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message` Look at line 100 as you can see `doInBackground(Discussion_server.java:100)`

Comment: Remove the `handler.postDelayed` from the constructor and do not use member function `onExecute()`. Just dismiss the dialog in `onPostExecute()`.

Comment: Thanks when i remove that log.d on 100th line it dint throw exception

Comment: Well tell us which code line that was. Fulle code please. I see no lines that could cause trouble.

Comment: Log.d("exc",e.getMessage());

Comment: Then e==null. Unbelievable. But... does your code work ok now?

Comment: @greenapps according to Javadoc of `getMessage()` "The detail message string of this Throwable instance (which may be null)" and that is why `e.printStackTrace()` is preferred over `getMessage()`

Comment: Thank you for that Setu. Very obliged. I mostly code both.

Comment: I also wondered how on the earth `e` could be null and then went on to read JavaDoc. well learnt something new today.

Comment: No now also Its not working in phone using kitkat version but in gingerbread version it workz how come?

Comment: Well post WHICH EXCEPTION?. Post a new logcat. Should we guess??